# Get visible height of an element instead of its actual height with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, height, visible

This post is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14125303/change-target-of-a-link-based-on-what-is-currently-displayed).
Please consider reading it as well. :-)

In the post I linked to, I figured the solution to my problem would be to change the target of a link if the visible height of a div is greater than that of another div. In my layout, all the divs I'm referring to have a height of 1100px. But that's not what I want to get. I'd like the script to get height of the div that is currently visible to the visitor, not its real height. Is there a way to do it using jQuery?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried? Check the function `jQuery.offset()`, along with the viewport information and element height will help you figure it out. Just a matter of addition and subtraction.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to do the same thing, and I'm having no luck.

Answer (score 8):

What you can do is take the elements position to the top of its parent container and then minus it from the parents container height. That will give you the visible height of the element.

```
$('#container').height() - $('#overflow').position().top
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mbZby/3/) showing this.

Comment: I'd never used .offset before, so first of all thank you for your answer which has taught me something. :-) I tried to come up with something using your method, but unfortunately it didn't work. Let's say I've got 3 divs that are all 1100px tall. My whole document is thus 3300px high. What I wanted to do is calculate the distance between the top of the last div and the top of the document and then change the target of my link according to the result. So: alert(3300 - $('#div3').offset().top)

Comment: When I was at the top of the document, it returned 1100, which was what I expected. But then I scrolled down a little bit, launched the script, but it still returned 1100. I thought it would give me a number that would be higher than 1100, but it didn't. So I guess .offset doesn't quite do what I thought it did and it just doesn't adapt to the current location of the scroll. :-/

Comment: @TomS. add  `$(window).scrollTop()` to your alert and it will give you what you want. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bplumb/mbZby/4/)

Comment: Fantastic! Again, I didn't know you could do that. Now I think I'll be able to use that to adapt the link appropriately. Thanks a lot! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the contents of the viewport DIV with another DIV. Target that DIV to read the height of all the contents as such:

JQuery: $('div#contents').height();

Layout:

```
<div id="viewport">
  <div id="contents">...all your div contents...</div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps. Good Luck.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have to use a fixed 1100px height? Cause you could also specify a max-height:1100px; and a height:100%; 
Depending on what you want to put inside the div you can of course get the current height by

```
$('.divclass').height();
```